# Block access to a CMS page or URL unless IP has access

Tags: magento-1.9, cms, security

I have a page that I do not want anyone to see except staff, there is no sensitive data on the page, I just do not want it accessible to everyone.

Is there a way to block access to website.co.uk/page for everyone not on my network?

I can set up password protection but I do not want this.

Thanks

*edit*

This works on the test site:

```
RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^xx\.xx\.xx\.xx$
    RewriteRule ^page/? - [F,NC]
```

But I have added it to the live site and I cannot access this page as I believe that the website is seeing my CDN IP address and not mine, is there a way around this?

Comment: If REMOTE_ADDR is not available or usable you can try HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR

Comment: Mind to add this as an answer @VincentHornikx?

Comment: Done @AnnaVölkl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If REMOTE_ADDR is not available or usable you can try HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR